# Automatic detection of server-side hack

Tags: javascript, security, code-signing

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to automatically detect the the fact that the HTML or javascript files on a server have been tampered with or changed by an attacker.

Our website, say `www.example.com/index.html`, when loaded in a browser, also loads `https://www.example.com/scripts/example.min.js` inside a `<script></script>` tag. If someone were to somehow hack into my server and swap out the `example.min.js` file with a modified one, is there any way I can automatically detect said intrusion.

One way to do it would be to run a program on an independent secure server that queried `https://example.com` every few minutes and compared the SHA of the `index.html` and `example.min.js` file to the last known good values.

Question 1:- assuming the polling interval is acceptable, is this a strong enough defense? Could the malicious code fool the polling code?

Question 2:- Is there a better way to reduce the window of risk other than reducing the polling interval, which creates unnecessary traffic.

Comment: The reason we would do this is we have set up our service such that a compromised server will cause almost no data loss, but malicious javascript code served up from our site and running on a user's browser can cause data loss and is more important to prevent.

Comment: Look into File Integrity Monitoring. e.g. OSSEC.

Answer (score 0):

Once you start doubting your own server-side, there lies madness.

Is there some reason you would be happier to trust the "independent secure server" that provides you with the checksum?

Comment: It makes it more difficult for an attacker because he now has to break into two completely independent servers and compromise their SSL certificates. You can never be 100% secure, but it is always better to have no single point of vulnerability.